# Fix moving files into year folder if exist a matching in .txt file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have files like this

```
Taxi driver.torrent
Tabu - Gohatto.txt
Troll 2 (1990)..zip
```

Inside my filelist.txt file I have files named like so

```
Troll 2 (1990) [BDrip 1080p - H264 - Ita Ac3] Horror, Commedia
Troll 2 (1990) [XviD - Ita Mp3]
Taxi Driver (1976) Mastered..
Tabù - Gohatto (N. Oshima, 1999)
```

I have just folders like

```
1976
1990
1999
```

I want to move files into correct year folder in this way

```
1976
  |__ Taxi driver.torrent

1990
  |__ Troll 2 (1990)..zip

1999
  |__ Tabu - Gohatto.txt
```

I use this path, folders

```
C:\Path
Test4.txt
script_powershell.ps1
```

I actually test with powershell 5 to move

```
$movies = @()
(get-content C:\Path\Test4.txt) | foreach($_){
$properties = @{
date = $_.substring($_.IndexOf("(")+1,4)
name = $_.substring(0,$_.IndexOf("("))
}
write-host $date
write-host $name

$movies += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}

$torrentFiles = dir $torrentPath

foreach($movie in $movies){
$datePath = "C:\Path\$($movie.date)"
if(-not(test-path $datePath)) {
new-item $datePath -ItemType "directory"
}
$words = ($movie.name -split '\s') | ?{ $_.Length -gt 1}
$significant = $words.Count
 foreach($torrentFile in $torrentFiles){
 $matchingWords = 0
  foreach($word in $words){
   if($torrentFile.BaseName -match $word){
    $matchingWords += 1
   }
  }
  if($matchingWords -ge $significant){
  Move-Item -path $torrentfile -Destination $datePath
 }
 }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This poweshell has many problems. For examples

```
Caccia al delitto
```

is moved in 1990 folder...but..Caccia al delitto is 1986..
Inside file text I have

```
Caccia a Ottobre Rosso (1990) [DivX - Ita Mp3] Guerra [CURA] Russia
Caccia a Ottobre Rosso (1990) [VP9 - Ita Eng Opus] Thriller
```

I have not a text string for Caccia al delitto (I remove it for test)

Comment: This is obviously a crossposting of https://superuser.com/questions/1348240/prevent-incorrect-moving-and-spam-foldering-if-filetext-contain-too-values/1348430#1348430 but with differing details. You could ease helping by using one identity sharing  the same details. See my answer on [SU](https://superuser.com/a/1348430/639112)

Comment: yes, you are right, I analyze in details your solution on SU and I answer you, look also my comment below on this page please. Problems seems about if you use a long list so spam folders are created and a wrong matching are performed so many files are moved in wrong year folders.. I test now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$movies = @()
$movieLocation = 'C:\Path'
$torrentPath = '.'

(get-content "$movieLocation\Test4.txt") | foreach($_) {

 # Check for braces.
 if (-not($_ -match ".*\(.*\).*")) {return}

 $properties = @{
  date = ($_ -replace ".+?\(.*?(\d{4}).*?\).*", '$1')
  name = $_.substring(0, $_.IndexOf("(")).Trim()
 }

 # Add items that have a 4 digit date.
 if ($properties.date -match "^\d{4}$") {
  'Name: "' + $properties.name + '" Date: "' + $properties.date + '"'

  $movies += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
 }
}

$torrentFiles = dir $torrentPath

foreach ($movie in $movies) {
 $datePath = "$movieLocation\$($movie.date)"

 if (-not(test-path "$datePath")) {
  new-item "$datePath" -ItemType "directory"
 }

 foreach ($torrentFile in $torrentFiles) {
  # Get percentage based on length.
  $pc = [int]($movie.name.length / $torrentFile.basename.length * 100)

  # Only between 80% and 100% in length.
  if ($pc -gt 100) {continue}
  if ($pc -lt 80) {continue}

  if ($torrentFile.basename -match $movie.name) {
   # Items that match.
   'Torrent: {0,-40} Date: {1,-5} Match: {2}' -f $torrentFile.basename, $movie.date, $movie.name

   if (-not(test-path "$datePath\$torrentfile")) {
    Move-Item -LiteralPath "$torrentPath\$torrentfile" -Destination "$datePath"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

A modest fix with the `date` using regex.
The `name` required a trim to remove trailing space.
I added a `test-path` before `move-item` in case the file is not found.

Long time since last used Powershell so could be perhaps improved more.
I tested in path `.` so hope `C:\Path` works just as well.

Comment: Problem is more complicated. I test with this list https://pastebin.com/raw/aRP94peb - all films of this list is of 1990. For my pack files, instead, I want to move only films of 1990 present in the filetext list in 1990 folder but.. if you try to test with this pack files https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yg-cDIGeLyIhv0ImOzKW7AGTT03EdNdm/view?usp=sharing you can see that many files are moved incorrectly also if is not present in the list and also many spam folders are generated.

Comment: You can see, for example, that *il_bandito_delle undici* is not in the filelist but is moved in 1990..or, just another example "Il Signore Degli Anelli - Il Ritorno Del Re" is not of 1990 year ..but is moved inside 1990 folder..
There are many problems if you have a long list but problem seems about how script is written

Comment: Thanks for the extra info and files. I added a check for the date being 4 digits. The name test is set at between 80% and 100% to match. Change the check to improve results. Ensure you set torrent path.

Comment: Hi Micheal, I test your script but there are still many files unprocessed, This pack you find unmoved files, for many is correct because there are strings without year but for other many files exists strings with year in text file, take a look please and test https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mVNNH2fb8jeNX1xrf4U7wt6ffwHbl_2X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have the previous list of about 300 names yet your latest link has about 8300 files. I tested with ps1 and get 1 match in about 135 seconds. I tested with py and get 20 matches in about 1.5 seconds. The py has a junk string replacement of about 30 words to remove `dvd5`, `dvd9` etc. Even with a list of 8300 names, the py may get matches of about 250 which is not much. Manual comparison shows that many files in the list do not exist so it seems not so much of a code issue.